# Testkitchen / KitchenCI - How to change console output colors?

Tags: zsh, tmux, test-kitchen, terminal-emulator, xfce

In the present case Ansible is used with KitchenCI/Testkitchen.

**Question**: How can I control the color of the kitchen output?

I tried different coloroptions in ansible but for kitchen I didn't find any options, but this bugs me, especially if the color of the kitchenoutput turns darkblue suddenly.

**Problem**:
The color of the kitchen-output changes, depending on ...I don't know...

(It doesn't change every run, but at some time, something initiates the colorchange and then it will keep the color for a while)

Sometimes it's an ugly pink:

[image]

Sometimes it's yellow, green or cyan:

[image]

... But most annoyingly, if it's darkblue, suddenly, and I can't read stuff:

[image]

Setup: i3, xfce4-terminal, zsh, sometimes in tmux, with `echo $TERM # -> screen-256color`

I think, if something in the folderstructure change, or something in the current ansible environment (the shell-options are always the same), e.g. if I clone the whole directory (at least thats where I recognized it last time). It can even be a different color if I change the directory in the "roles" directory. But all in all I can't point my finger at it and I would be glad for help.

If more Information is needed, I would gladly provide it.

**Update:**
Maybe it's something in ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/...
Theres a lot of code regarding "tty"

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question (that's still interesting! because I don't want the color to change), but targets the underlying problem, meaning the non-readablitity of the blue color.

The reason was the configuration of "xfce4-terminal".

In xfce4-terminal one can define the representation for colors in the right-click: 'preferences' > 'colors' > 'Palette'

If a background-color is set, that would conflict with the color "blue" (dark blue), the representation for the color "blue" can be change (e.g. to grey, or light blue, or everything else).

See the screenshot:
[image]